# Why do I get this "attaching the Script debugger...failed" err msg?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, javascript-debugger

When I run (F5) an asp.net mvc4 site from VS 2010 (I've made no changes to anything - HTML, CSS, or JScript), the page displays, but I get:

*Attaching the Script debugger to process '[NNNN] iexplore.exe' on machine 'DUCKBILLEDPLATYPUS' failed. A debugger is already attached.*

What is causing this, and how can I rectify it?

Comment: Yes, sort of - ever since I downloaded a USB-Sniffer app, IE10 has been busted (extremely unstable, crashes when the temperature fluctuates more than one thousandth of a degree), so I switched to Chrome (thankfully, IT had already installed it on my machine).